# Id isn't returning anything in the Google App Engine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I tried select * from post which returns all posts. How can I do a select just for one post using the post_id? I've tried

```
Select * from post where id='5629499534213120' 
select * from post where post_id='5629499534213120' 
select * from post where NAME/ID='5629499534213120'
```

and it didn't return anything.

Below is an image of my post table

[image: Post Table]

Below is a detailed view.

[image: detailed view]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, you probably want to be doing a query with a key literal:

```
SELECT * FROM Post WHERE __key__ = KEY('Post', 5629499534213120)
```

An additional thing to note -- Keys can have either string or integer ids.  By default, the IDs are integers so I used an integer in the query above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I was able to get it working using

```
SELECT * FROM Post WHERE __key__ = Key(blogs, 'default', Post, 5629499534213120)
```